# Pass data between different views in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a basic view that retrieves some data, renders my page and sends some data to this page:

```
def myview(request)

    one = values.objects.get(user=request.user).address
    two = values.objects.get(user=request.user).number

    return render(request, "main/mytemplate.html", 
                  context={'address': one, 'numbers': two})
```

So the values retrieved by those two queries are shown on my page.

Now, on the same page, called **mytemplate.html**, i'm using another view, which is supposed to handle a form and some other operations:

```
def secondview(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'button1' in request.POST:
            form = MyForm(request.POST)
            # check whether it's valid:
            if form.is_valid():
                profile = form.save(commit=False)
                profile.user = request.user
                profile.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)


    else:
        form = MyForm()

    return HttpResponse('it works!')
```

How can i use the data retrieved by those two queries in the second view? The queries are executed when the page is loaded by the first view. Then, in the same page the second view is used. I want to use the two variables `one` and `two` in the second view. Is there a way to do this in Django?

*Why don't you make the same queries in the second view?* Because i would like the second form to be as fast as possible in terms of reload, without having to do a DB query each time that view is used. Also, since i already retrieved those values when the page is opened, it would be a waste to do that again.

I don't know if this question is clear enough, but the core of it is: can i pass variables/data between two views in django?

Comment: Can you include your form and template?

Comment: I would not bother passing the data between views if you have not benchmarked the performance of the queryset. You would need a major bottleneck on the database layer to even consider such solution.
"Premature optimization is root of all evil"

Comment: @KamilNiski i know, the fact is that querying the DB takes that 1 unnecessary second that i don't want to waste

Comment: @Jack022 is it really taking 1 second? Looks like that query is not built properly or queryset retrieves too much data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have few options:

1. Simplest way: include this data in request to the second view (as part of the form data, see an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58912197/3722635) below). You might even use a single view: if POST was send - store data else do request and show it on a page.
2. Use cache for that (see an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58889252/3722635) below) - But I'd recommend to use [Django built-in package](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/). Here is a [basic example how to use it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/#basic-usage)
3. Use [Django Sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/) (see an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58883705/3722635) below) - it is working option despite of that they have another purpose. When customer is loaded Django will load full session record, so you'll have all data in `request.session` variable. But that is bad practice: you can get a lot of data duplication and increased database memory consumption.
4. Use API (e.g. using [DjangoRestFramework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)) together with usual Django app. So you'll just get data you need, and when you need. These API requests can also be cached so it is fast solution.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for your answer, everything is clearer now!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use session to pass data across views. A session works like a temporary server storage and keeps the needed data in a dictionary form.

For instance, add the following lines to `myview`:

```
request.session['one'] = one
request.session['two'] = two
```

Then, retrieve the data in `secondview` by referring to the session:

```
one = request.session['one']
two = request.session['two']
```

Comment: One should be cautious with storing objects in session. Remember that anything you put in the session has to be serializable. The safest way is to store only primitive types

Comment: Nice! But what happens if the data i want to store is sensitive data? Is it a safe way to go?

Answer (score 2):

you can use cookies. but if you want more secure your request i suggest to you using [redis](https://redis.io/) and the [python client](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py) for redis

file settings.py

```
redis = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
```

file views.py

```
def view1(request):

    redis.set("foo", "boo")

def view2(request):

    boo = redis.get("foo")
```

Comment: What happens if the data i want to use is sensitive data? Is it still a safe way to go?

Comment: what's do you mean of "sensitive data". you can config your redis server. for example persist data to storage.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just saving the results of the two queries as hidden fields in the form rendered by the first template ?

```
<form ...>

    <input type="hidden" id="address" name="address" value="{{address}}">
    <input type="hidden" id="numbers" name="numbers" value="{{numbers}}">

    ...
```

Then, you can either add 'address' and 'numbers' form fields to MyForm

```
address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)
...
```

or just retrieve the values from request.POST

Comment: This seems the right way to go for now, thanks for your example!